# Changing a 3 gang Australian light switch to a 3 gang Smart switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, smart-switch

I am wanting to replace my old 3 gang switch with the latest 'smart' 3 gang switch, but I'm a little bit confused about how to wire it correctly. Obviously I know that I should employ a licensed electrician to do this job for me, but was wondering if anyone out there might be able to help me out with simple instructions on how to wire the light.

I have included images below of the existing and new switchess.

---

[The existing switch](https://hpm.com.au/product/switch-3-gang-excel/)

[image: The existing switch and wiring]

The switch on the LHS and the switch on the RHS in this image are for lights that do NOT have separate/alternate switch's within the home, where as the switch in the middle has an alternate switch located within the home (ie. the middle switch is 1 of 2 switch's that control the same light).

---

[The new switch](https://www.bunnings.com.au/deta-grid-connect-smart-triple-gang-touch-light-switch_p0161014)

[image: The new wifi/smart switch]

Comment: Are there any other wires in the box the old switch is mounted?  If the house is older it might just use what we call switch loops(just hot and switched hot) with no neutral.  Most smart switches require a neutral(some don't) and make a five minute job into hours/days in older houses.

Answer (score 4):

That thing where a light is controlled by switches in 2 locations, is called 2-way wiring in the UK.  No idea what it's called in AU/NZ.

### This isn't going to work with your existing 2-way wiring.

I'm looking right at the wiring diagram for the switch, it has no support whatsoever for 2-way switching.

Further it does not have any support for a "switch loop" 2-way.  It's difficult to discern because you aren't showing us all the wiring in the box, but it appears the existing 2-way is powered from the other end.

For that control, you will need to install a system-compatible smart switch at the other location, or do something completely different. What options you have depends on the wiring topology of the entire system of 2-ways + lamp(s).  Which you are not showing us. So I can't say.

Comment: Also 2 way in NZ/Aus,

Answer (score 1):

It will work but you need to buy a second deta wifi smart switch (let's say the other switch is a single gang) to control the 2 way light switch. You create an automation (program) on the second single gang switch(which needs to be powered but it is not wired on the A1 out) to turn on when the A# switch in the first 3 gang switch is pressed. Then another automation for when the switch is off.

Here is a link on how to set up the automation.
https://youtu.be/2qNCIXC44JA

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).